# MongoDB find filter by month and year

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

This query works in filtering the 12/2018 posts..

```
db.collection.find({
  "$expr": {
    "$eq": [{ "$year": "$timestamp" }, 2018],
    "$eq": [{ "$month": "$timestamp" }, 12]
  }
});
```

But if I reverse the year and month then it shows all 2018 posts instead.

```
db.collection.find({
  "$expr": {
    "$eq": [{ "$month": "$timestamp" }, 12],
    "$eq": [{ "$year": "$timestamp" }, 2018]
  }
});
```

Why is that? I can't understand it.

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript objects can't have more than one key with the same name, but you're using the `$eq` key twice here so only the second is used.

Instead, combine the two expressions using [`$and`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/and/#exp._S_and):

```
db.collection.find({
  "$expr": {
    "$and": [
      {"$eq": [{ "$year": "$timestamp" }, 2018]},
      {"$eq": [{ "$month": "$timestamp" }, 12]}
    ]
  }
});
```